# Connection between a simple matter wave and Heisenberg's uncertainty relation

Tags: wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

When looking at the wave function of a particle, I usually prefer to write

$$
    \Psi(x,t) = A \exp(i(kx - \omega t))
$$

since it reminds me of classical waves for which I have an intuition ($k$ tells me how it moves through space ($x$) and $\omega$ tells me how it moves through time ($t$), roughly speaking). However, I noticed that you can translate this from the $(k,\omega)$ into the $(p,E)$ space by extracting $\hbar$:

$$
    \Psi(x,t) = A \exp(i(px - Et)/\hbar)
$$

When looking at this representation, I couldn't help but be remembered of the uncertainty relations

$$
    \Delta p \Delta x \geq \hbar\\
    \Delta E \Delta t \geq \hbar
$$

This *cannot* be a coincidence, but the derivation of these relations (as described e.g. on Wikipedia) are simply over my head and my textbook merely motivates them with an argument based on wave packets.

**What is the connection here? Is there an intuitive explanation for the recurrence of both uncertainty relations in the wave function of a matter particle?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely right. In fact, the uncertainty relations are a *direct* consequence of this wave nature and the "conjugated" variables being $p \leftrightarrow x$ and $E \leftrightarrow t$.

I will attempt a simple explanation. Remember that the wavefunction gives you a probability amplitude for finding the particle at some location $x$ at some time $t$? The probability to find the particle at some point $x$ at time $t$ is given by $|\Psi(x,t)|^2$.

Now here's the catch: If you put your plane wave into that equation, you'll find that $|\Psi(x,t)|^2 = A$, independent of $x$ and $t$. So for your plane wave, the particle has equal probability to be *anywhere*. In terms of uncertainty, then, we could say that the uncertainty in position is at a maximum, and so is the uncertainty in time.

What about momentum and energy? Well, your plane wave has a definite momentum of $p = \hbar k$ and a definite energy of $E = \hbar \omega$, so their uncertainty is zero. This is an extreme case of the uncertainty relation: Certainty in one variable means maximum uncertainty in the other variable.

Any other possible form of the wave function can always be written as a sum of plane waves (that's the Fourier theorem):

$$\Psi(x,t) = \int dE \int dk A(k,E) \exp(i(kx-E/\hbar t)$$

You can think of $\Psi(x,t)$ as the wavefunction in position and time domain and $A(k,E)$ as the wavefunction in momentum and frequency domain, and the conversion between those two is achieved via the Fourier transform.

You can now mathematically show how if $\Psi(x,t)$ is "narrow" (i.e. position has low uncertainty) then $A(k,E)$ must be broad and vice versa.

The intuition behind that: You need to add up *a lot* of plain waves with lots of different momenta to go from the broad plain wave distribution to a narrow wave packet, but this then implies that you have high uncertainty in momentum.